# WebView and Status Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

When I run my web app WebView takes over the status bar, as in the picture: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/priyo.jpg

I'd like to be separated.
An example is this: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k37ng.jpg

How can I set the WebView to have this effect ?

Sorry for the links , but I can’t upload pictures because I'm new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both UIWebView and WKWebView classes inherit from UIView, which means we can boil down the problem as a UIStatusBar instance incorrectly overlapping a UIView instance.

If you are using Auto Layout in a Storyboard, create a constraint (with a value of 0) between the top of the Web View and the bottom of the UIViewController view's Top Layout Guide. By relating your constraint to the [Top Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW3), your Web View will always respond to the status bar height should iOS designers ever change it.

[image]

If you are rendering the Web View programmatically and do not wish to you use Auto Layout, check into [CGRectOffset](http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/#cgrectoffset) and [CGRectInset](http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/#cgrectinset) to manually set the frame of your Web View. At the time of this post, the status bar has a height of 20 points.

**UPDATE 12/1/17**

Preceding the introduction of the first iPhone with a non-rectangular screen (the iPhone X), Apple introduced [Safe Areas](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area) in iOS 11 to manage a UIView's relationships with the boundaries of a device. In addition to managing physical boundaries of the device, the Safe Area observes software boundaries such as a virtual home button.

Unless your app requires custom drawing, I recommend relying solely on Autolayout going forward. Within a UIViewController, relate your subview's topAnchor to the UIViewController view's safeLayoutGuide.topAnchor, and so on.